# Get nothing from Firebase via Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to google firebase and cloud functions.
I just did kind of helloworld:

1. Connect to Cloud firestore[beta], which contains more than 100,000 records
2. Retrieve top 1 record.

The code goes like this:

```
    'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

console.log(mydump(functions.config().firebase));
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const tokens = [];
    const html = [];
    var oldItemsQuery = admin.database().ref();

    html.push("==============begin========================");

    return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        console.log("once value, snapshot key:" + snapshot.key 
            +",val:" +snapshot.val()
            +",hasChild/profile:" +snapshot.hasChild("profile")
            +",hasChild/everyday:" +snapshot.hasChild("everyday")
            +",numChildren:" +snapshot.numChildren()
            +",toJSON:" +snapshot.toJSON()

        );

        html.push("============end===================");  
        response.send(html.join("<br>\n"));

      });
});
```

I believe this code is very simple. But the result is not as expect when I access the url in my browser.
https://us-central1-xxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld?r=125

I got message in console

```
once value, snapshot key:null,val:null,hasChild/profile:false,hasChild/everyday:false,numChildren:0,toJSON:null
```

that means there are no records in my database. I tried the following code, but result is the same.

```
var oldItemsQuery = admin.database().ref("");
var oldItemsQuery = functions.database.ref('/{playerId}/profile').orderByChild('timezone').limitToFirst(1);
  //var oldItemsQuery = admin.database().ref('/{playerId}/profile').orderByChild('timezone').limitToFirst(1);
```

Thank you. I spent 3 days but could work it out.

Comment: admin.database.enableLogging(true); I add the line at the top of script and get console message. it seems everything goes OK

Comment: Can you post your database structure please?

Comment: Your code connects to the Firebase Realtime Database. But in your description you say that you connect to Cloud Firestore. The two are different databases. To which one did you add the records?

Comment: Hello , Frank, I think you get the point. I believe I am using Cloud Firestore [beta]. So what connection codes should go with Cloud Firestore [beta] if I would like to access it in my Cloud function?  I will try :const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();

Comment: hello Rosário,  thank you for reply. the schema is quit simple /userid001; /userid001/profile; that's it

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it works :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); 
var db = admin.firestore();
```

I have to say it's a silly question. But please keep it there. I believe I am not the only one meets the problem. Thank Frank give me the clue